# Points, Vectors, Dot Product & Cross Product of python

Tags: python, math

Need help with this of python

Write a program with 3 functions to find out the
(function 1) dot product, (function 2) angle, and
(function 3) cross product of two vectors.

1. Program should ask a user to input three
   points in 3D space such as (x1, y1, z1), (x2,
   y2, z2) (x3, y3, z3).
2. Find two vectors
3. Find dot product,
4. Find the angle between two vectors
5. Find the cross product of two vectors

Comment: It's generally frowned on to ask others to do your homework without 1) showing your work so far, 2) describing where you are stuck, and 3) not asking others to do your homework at all. Actually, just do it yourself.

Comment: This might be helpful http://vpython.org/contents/docs/vector.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import library `visual` to use the following functions.

Given vector `v1` and `v2`:

To find the angle:

```
diff_angle(v1,v2)
```

or

```
v1.diff_angle(v2)
```

This gives the angle in radians.

---

To get the dot product:

```
dot(v1,v2)
```

can also be written as:

```
mag(v1)*mag(v2)*cos(diff_angle(v1,v2))
```

or

```
v1.dot(v2))
```

---

To find cross product:

```
cross(v1,v2)
```

or:

```
mag(v1)*mag(v2)*sin(diff_angle(v1,v2))
```

or:

```
v1.cross(v2)
```

---

Given two point `p1` and `p2, to find vector from`p1`to`p2`:

```
vector(p2)-vector(p1)
```

Comment: It might be helpful to mention where the `diff_angle` function is coming from in your answer.  It's not standard Python (or even NumPy).

Comment: @MarkDickinson You need to import library `visual`

Comment: You should include that in your answer!  (Otherwise, anyone who comes across this answer has to read through the comments to figure out the necessary context.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for suggestion. I have added it in my answer.

Comment: To get vector,  `pip install vpython`